# How to find this string in multiple files with grep?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to use grep to find the string "init()" in all the files that end in .js in a directory.

I tried this

```
grep "init()" *.js
```

but it didn't work. Why not? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try escaping the parentheses: `grep "init\(\)" *.js`

It is actually a regular expression, where `(` and `)` are special characters.